# How can my web app save data after each GET request it receives?

Tags: python, github, heroku

I'm a python programmer who is new to making web apps. My app works as a webhook that responds to GET requests by returning a random message from a list of different messages, stored in a text file like `messages.txt`. Here's a simplification of my problem.

Let's say `messages.txt` stores a list of strings that looks like this:

```
Apples
Bananas
Oranges
Grapes
```

Each time that my app receives a GET request, I want it to return one of the strings from `messages.txt,` **but** it will only return the same string a second time after every other message has been sent. For example, after three GET requests, if "Apples" "Bananas" and "Grapes" have each been sent, I would want my app to *remember this information* and then decide to respond with "Oranges" since that hasn't been sent before.

My question is: **How can I implement a way for my app to remember which messages have been sent, so it can choose a message that hasn't yet been sent?**

My app is powered by Heroku and runs via GitHub, and because Heroku pulls the source code from GitHub to run the app, I can't store the information I need without committing and pushing to the repo after each GET request. What's the cleanest solution?

Comment: If you are not worried about keeping state between builds (i.e. losing track of the last served string when you update the repo) you can make a singleton that keeps the next string (and possibly all strings if there aren't too many) in memory. Otherwise you can simply use a database (such as the free PostgreSQL instance of Heroku).

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for the suggestion. I'm inexperienced with databases so I'll look into Heroku Postgre, which I didn't know about.